# Jquery: Use SetInterval when clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple javascript jquery code:

http://jsfiddle.net/reX2N/

I thought it would work but it isn't! I'm not getting any errors or anything, does anyone know why?

```
var colors = ['red','green','blue'];

$('button').on('click',function(){
    var index = $(this).parent().index();
    setInterval(function(){
        $(this).parent().css('background',colors[index]);
        index < 3 ? index++ : index = 0;
    }, 1000);
});
```

html code

```
   <div class="titleBox">
       <button>Click meh!</button>
   </div>
   <div class="titleBox">
      <button>Click meh!</button>
   </div>
   <div class="titleBox">
       <button>Click meh!</button>
   </div>

.titleBox {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    float:left;
    border:1px solid;
    opacity:.5
}
.titleBox[style^="background"] {
    opacity:1;
}
```

Comment: Because `this` is window scope.

Comment: `this` is not the button in the setInterval scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign `$(this)` outside of `setTimeout()`, then pass the variable into the timeout function by reference:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/7Y3hn/)

```
$('button').on('click',function(){
    var self = $(this);
    var index = $(this).parent().index();
    setInterval(function(){
        self.parent().css('background',colors[index]);
        index < 3 ? index++ : index = 0;
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: It'd be nice to explain to the OP that `this` becomes something else inside `setInterval`, in this case, the global object. Another way to fix it is by using `Function.bind`

Comment: @JuanMendes Your comment will explain it. 1+ to your answer though. I  didn't know about `.bind`.

Comment: You can also just pass the `event` object and use `$(event.currentTarget)`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that inside of `setInterval`, `this` will typically point to the global object (window), not the DOM element as in the click handler. You have two options:

**Store `this` as a separate variable** and use that from the `setInterval` anonymous function

```
$('button').on('click',function(){
    var self = $(this);
    var index = $(this).parent().index();
    setInterval(function(){
        self.parent().css('background',colors[index]);
        index < 3 ? index++ : index = 0;
    }, 1000);
});
```

**Bind your `setInterval` handler** so that you don't lose `this` in the anonymous function

```
$('button').on('click',function(){
    var index = $(this).parent().index();
    setInterval(function(){
        $(this).parent().css('background',colors[index]);
        index < 3 ? index++ : index = 0;
    }.bind(this), 1000);
});
```

Comment: To be IE8 compatible an alternative for `bind()` is jQuery's `$.proxy()`

Answer (score 2):

This will solve your problem, change your js in this way:

```
$('button').on('click',function(){
    var index = $(this).parent().index();
    var $el = $(this);
    setInterval(function(){
        $el.parent().css('background',colors[index]);
        index < 3 ? index++ : index = 0;
    }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, since you have your answers, would be to use the `event` object passed as the `arguments` of an eventHandler (onclick, onchange, ...)

```
$('button').on('click',function(ev){
    var index = $(this).parent().index();
    setInterval(function(){
        $(ev.currentTarget).parent().css('background',colors[index]);
        index < 3 ? index++ : index = 0;
    }, 1000);
});
```

Now I notice you repeat some stuff, so perhaps you can do it like this:

```
$('button').on('click',function(){
    var parent = $(this).parent(),
        index = parent.index();

    setInterval(function(){
        parent.css('background',colors[index]);
        index < 3 ? index += 1 : index = 0;
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: This will work as long as the button doesn't have any child elements. Otherwise, that's what would be in currentTarget when clicked